# Xcode - Button looks good in storyboard but not on emulator

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistoryboard

When I work with buttons in the storyboard they look good, like this:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/vsz3gwd5x/]

But when i run the app they turn out like this:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/uwftwhne9/]

Do you guys know why?

Here are som settings:

[image: UI Settings Panel]

Thanks!

Comment: AutoLayout ?
But I'd also use the background of the button, after switching its mode into Custom (and not plain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have put image in **Image** attribute of inspector.
Put that image in **Background** attribute of inspector.

Answer (score 1):

top one in your attribute inspector **Type**, change that to **Custom** from **Rounded**.
By the way, our iOS has `simulator` not `emulator`. In android sdk we call it `emulator` ;)

Answer (score 0):

check the view content mode in the attribute inspector it's in the fourth tab on your right colum. content mode can be scale to fill, aspect fit and a bunch of other possibilities. This will affect how it is presented. Check also in the fifth tab how your button autosizing is set.